# Account is not allowed to suggest edits

Tags: support, editing

I received the following error upon trying to preview my edit to [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/32602/344) in the Android app:

> Please fix the following:
>   Account is not allowed to suggest edits

Comment: On Meta or on Main? On which question/answer?

Comment: @ProgramFOX updated question.

Comment: I found a post about it on MSE. Suggesting edits is currently not yet implemented in the API, so it won't work on the Android and iOS app: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/208471/229438

Comment: @ProgramFOX thanks, you might want to submit that as an answer.

Comment: Yep, I've done that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently, suggesting edits is not yet implemented in the API, so it won't work on the Android and iOS app. See this question on Meta Stack Exchange: [Android app should send edits to edit queue if necessary rather than rejecting them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/208471/229438)